# Is it possible to install pyarrow with cuda integration using conda or pip?

Tags: pip, conda, pyarrow

I'm trying to use `pyarrow.cuda`. But after installation of `pyarrow` by `conda` or `pip` I get following error:

```
>>> import pyarrow.cuda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/b1es/miniconda3/envs/seismic/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/cuda.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyarrow._cuda import (Context, IpcMemHandle, CudaBuffer,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow._cuda'
```

This is a fresh `conda` environment created in following way:

```
$ conda create -n seismic -c conda-forge python numpy scipy sympy matplotlib numba pandas pillow pyspark tqdm pyarrow
...
$ conda activate seismic
$ python -c 'from numba import cuda ; print(cuda.current_context())'
<CUDA context c_void_p(93844987691120) of device 0>
$ python -c 'import pyarrow ; print(pyarrow.__version__)'
0.14.1
$ python -c 'import pyarrow.cuda'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/b1es/miniconda3/envs/seismic/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/cuda.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyarrow._cuda import (Context, IpcMemHandle, CudaBuffer,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow._cuda'
```

I also created a fresh `conda` env where `pyarrow` was installed from `pip`, result was the same.

Comment: The way your question is currently phrased, it's impossible to tell how exactly you set up that environment. Please start with a fresh environment using only `conda`. Have you installed CUDA with `conda`? Or is there a pyarrow build that depends on CUDA? When trying with `pip`, use another separate environment.

Comment: @RolandWeber I edited my question. What do you mean by asking if I installed CUDA with conda? CUDA Toolkit was installed before miniconda.

Comment: conda has its own packages for the CUDA toolkit. If you've installed the toolkit outside of conda, it probably won't be found automatically. https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cudatoolkit

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. First I created environment, next I installed `cudatoolkit` and after this `pyarrow`.